# One Item in Dropdown menu disable and gray out a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, textbox

For some reason I cannot figure out how to do this in reverse. What I am trying to do is have a drop down menu where there are 4 choices as well as a select status and when you choose the last choice (exempt) I want it to gray out and disable the odometer reading. As well as not prompt saying it's required anymore. For some reason this does the opposite unlocks textbox on exempt and disables textbox for everything else.

```
<cfselect 
  name="ostatus" 
  id="ostatus" 
  required="yes" 
  onchange="oreading.disabled=(b=(selectedIndex!=4));b||oreading.focus()" 
  message="Please select odometer status."
>
  <option value="">Select Status</option>
  <option value="Actual Mileage">Actual Mileage</option>    
  <option value="Mileage Exceeds Mechanical Limits">Mileage Exceeds Mechanical Limits</option>
  <option value="Not Actual Mileage">Not Actual Mileage</option>    
  <option value="Exempt">Exempt</option>
</cfselect>

<label for="oreading">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reading:</label>
<cfinput 
  type="text" 
  name="oreading" 
  id="oreading" 
  validateat="onSubmit" 
  validate="noblanks" 
  required="yes" 
  message="Please enter odometer reading." 
  value="#form.oreading#" 
  onfocus="this.select()" 
  disabled="disabled"
>
```

Comment: I suggest moving the js commands to a function inside a srcipt tag.  That will make it easier to look at things like selectedIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking on how to do this, this is what I figured out!

```
<script language="javascript">
function dis_able()
{
    if(document.form.ostatus.value != 'Others')
        document.form.oreading.disabled=0;
    else
        document.form.oreading.disabled=1;
}
</script>

<cfselect
 name="ostatus" 
 id="ostatus" 
 required="yes" 
 message="Please select odometer status." 
 size="1" 
 onChange="dis_able()"
>
 <option value="">Select Status</option>
 <option value="Actual Mileage">Actual Mileage</option>    
 <option value="Mileage Exceeds Mechanical Limits">Mileage Exceeds Mechanical Limits</option>
 <option value="Not Actual Mileage">Not Actual Mileage</option>    
 <option value="Others">Exempt</option>
</cfselect>       

<label for="oreading">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reading:</label>
<cfinput 
 type="text" 
 name="oreading" 
 id="oreading" 
 validateat="onSubmit" 
 validate="noblanks" 
 required="yes" 
 message="Please enter odometer reading." 
 value="#form.oreading#" 
 onfocus="this.select()"
>
```